# Force php to look at Document Root

Tags: php, require-once

So I was messing around with the twitter api, and I want to include this file in the footer for every page. The footer is loaded via phps require_once function. The problem is I can't use a full url because of url file acsess being turned off for obvious reasons. So I tried to use

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']('/lib/twitter/base.php');
```

But that failed. What am I doing wrong or how can I do this better?

Comment: That will try to use the value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as the name of a function, then execute it with `/lib/twitter/base.php` as an argument and then include that result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/twitter/base.php');
```